# Spring Data JPA. How to stop a recursive query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a task. Create a web application similar to a REST employee directory stored in an embedded database. Each employee record should include information of his department and his manager. Manager's manager should be usually null.If parameter named full_chain exists and is set to true then full manager chain should be written (include employee`s manager, manager of manager, manager of manager of manager and so on up to the organization head).

Employee class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride( name = "firstName", column = @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")),
            @AttributeOverride( name = "lastName", column = @Column(name = "LASTNAME")),
            @AttributeOverride( name = "middleName", column = @Column(name = "MIDDLENAME"))
    })
    private FullName fullName;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="POSITION")
    private Position position;
    @Column(name="HIREDATE")
    private LocalDate hired;
    @Column(name="SALARY")
    private BigDecimal salary;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager")
    private Employee manager;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department")
    private Department department;
```

SQL schema

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(
    ID       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME     VARCHAR(14),
    LOCATION VARCHAR(13)
);
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR(10),
    LASTNAME   VARCHAR(10),
    MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(10),
    POSITION   VARCHAR(9),
    MANAGER    INTEGER,
    HIREDATE   DATE,
    SALARY     DOUBLE,
    DEPARTMENT INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPNO FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (ID)
);
COMMIT;
```

Implemented via PagingAndSortingRepository. Now Employees are displayed with full_chain parameters. How do I set up the class config so that the Employee's manager does not have a manager.
Output example

```
{
  "id": 7698,
  "fullName": {
    "firstName": "JOHN",
    "lastName": "BLAKE",
    "middleName": "MARIA"
  },
  "position": "MANAGER",
  "hired": "1981-05-01",
  "salary": 2850.00000,
  "manager": {
    "id": 7839,
    "fullName": {
      "firstName": "JOHN",
      "lastName": "KING",
      "middleName": "MARIA"
    },
    "position": "PRESIDENT",
    "hired": "1981-11-17",
    "salary": 5000.00000,
    "manager": null,
    "department": null
  },
  "department": {
    "id": 30,
    "fullName": "SALES",
    "position": "CHICAGO"
  }
}
```